# ROLLING CORRELATION with ARRAYFORMULA (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, correlation, array-formulas

I want to create a 'Rolling Correlation' between two columns (data in A and B), with 5 rows interval.

Example:

```
formula in cell C1: CORREL(A1:A5,B1:B5)
formula in cell C2: CORREL(A2:A6,B2:B6)
formula in cell C3: CORREL(A3:A7,B3:B7)
and so on...
```

Is it possible to do it with an `ARRAYFORMULA`?

Answer (score 0):

try like this in C1:

```
={CORREL(A1:A5, B1:B5);
  CORREL(A2:A6, B2:B6);
  CORREL(A3:A7, B3:B7)}
```

or like this and drag down:

```
=CORREL(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"&ROW()+5), INDIRECT("B"&ROW()&":B"&ROW()+5))
```

Comment: Thanks player0. I am avoiding 'dragging down' because it's a lot of data with variable number of rows. I am trying something like: `=ARRAYFORMULA(CORREL(OFFSET(A1:A,0,0,5,1),OFFSET(B1:B,0,0,5,1)))`